# What is the Lucas counterpart to the Fibonacci identity $5F_n^2\pm~4=\lambda^2$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

It's a well-known rule that a number $x$ belongs to the Fibonnaci Sequence iff:
$$\begin{align}5x^2\pm~4&=\lambda^2&\lambda\in\mathbb Z\end{align}$$
In other words, if and only if $5x^2\pm~4$ is a perfect square.

What is the equivalent identity for testing whether a number is a member of the Lucas sequence?

Comment: The simple way to motivate the existence of this condition, is to look at the connection between Pell's Equation and the recurrence relation of it's underlying solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent identity for Lucas numbers is:
$$5L_n^2\pm~20=\lambda^2$$
as can be found [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Artan_Luma/publication/215530015_Relationship_between_Fibonacci_and_Lucas_sequences_and_their_application_in_symmetric_cryptosystems/file/c713017f2ffd82fcb9228e25653dc8a8.pdf). To put it another way, a number $x$ is in the Lucas Sequence if and only if $5L_n^2\pm~20$ is a perfect square. Just think $4$ for Fibonacci, $20$ for Lucas.

Matter of fact, it can be shown that $\lambda=5F_n$:
$$\begin{align}5F_n^2\pm~4&=L_n^2\\
5F_n^2&=L_n^2\pm~4\\
25F_n^2&=5(L_n^2\pm~4)\\
25F_n^2&=5L_n^2\pm~20\end{align}$$
This is very intriguing!